# Stored procedure with nullable value in date field

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

In this stored procedure , in a where condition if @startDate and @EndDate values are null then how it can be handle using  COALESCE.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  dbo.SP_ManageLeaveSearch

  @StartDate datetime,
  @EndDate datetime,

  @UserName CHAR(100), 
  @MarketID INT 

AS
BEGIN
    SELECT d1.UserName,c1.HouseName,c.StartDate,c.EndDate
        FROM  table1   c    
        Inner  JOIN table2  d1 ON c.UserID = d1.UserID


WHERE 
     (

        (
            (@StartDate BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate)
            OR 
            (@EndDate BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate) 
            OR
                (
                (@StartDate <= Startdate AND @EndDate>=EndDate)
                )
        )  
        AND
        (

             d1.UserName = COALESCE(@UserName, d1.UserName) 
        ) 

)

 END
```

Thnaks in advance.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  dbo.ManageLeaveSearch

  @StartDate datetime = NULL,
  @EndDate datetime = NULL,

  @UserName CHAR(100) = NULL, 
  @MarketID INT 

AS
BEGIN
    SELECT d1.UserName,c1.HouseName,c.StartDate,c.EndDate
        FROM  table1   c    
        Inner  JOIN table2  d1 ON c.UserID = d1.UserID


WHERE 
     COALESCE(@StartDate,StartDate) <= EndDate AND
     StartDate <= COALESCE(@EndDate,EndDate) AND
     d1.UserName = COALESCE(@UserName, d1.UserName) 

 END
```

Notes:

- *Don't* name stored procedures with an `sp_` prefix - it's reserved for Microsoft's [system procedures](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).
- I've gone with simpler conditions for determining an overlap exists. An overlap exists between two ranges if range 1 starts before range 2 ends, **and** range 2 starts before range 1 ends.
- I've specified defaults for those parameters that should be nullable.

Comment: In this condition didn't get the record which have start date and end date are same day.

Comment: @Ashok - that's just a change of `<` to `<=`, which I've now done. You didn't really define your inputs, and I didn't carefully consider the edge conditions in your original query. It's easy to adjust (by deciding on using `<` or `<=`) whether you want the endpoints of ranges to be inclusive or exclusive. Usually, if there was a time component also, you'd probably want the `@endDate`/`EndDate` to be exclusive, not inclusive.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_ManageLeaveSearch

  @StartDate DATETIME,
  @EndDate DATETIME,

  @UserName CHAR(100), 
  @MarketID INT 

AS BEGIN

    SELECT 
          d1.UserName
        , c.HouseName
        , c.StartDate
        , c.EndDate
    FROM dbo.table1 c    
    JOIN dbo.table2 d1 ON c.UserID = d1.UserID
    WHERE d1.UserName = ISNULL(@UserName, d1.UserName) 
        AND (
              ISNULL(@StartDate, StartDate) BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
            OR 
              ISNULL(@EndDate, EndDate) BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
        )

 END
```

Comment: Can the condition to compare the dates be omitted if the parameter is null? say `@StartDate is null or (@StartDate between StartDate AND EndDate)`. Pardon the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You've overly complicated things.  This should work for you, and is as simple of a query as I know of.  I prefer this syntax because in most of my use cases, the ...OR @UserName IS NULL can be removed from the query before it is even executed thereby making a very simple, fast execution.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  dbo.SP_ManageLeaveSearch

  @StartDate datetime,
  @EndDate datetime,

  @UserName CHAR(100), 
  @MarketID INT 

AS
BEGIN
SELECT d1.UserName,c1.HouseName,c.StartDate,c.EndDate
FROM table1 c    
JOIN table2 d1
    ON c.UserID = d1.UserID
WHERE (@StartDate<=EndDate OR @StartDate IS NULL)
AND (@EndDate>=StartDate OR @EndDate IS NULL)
AND (d1.UserName = @UserName OR @UserName IS NULL)
END
```

Comment: The idea is that if `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` are both NULL, the query preprocessor will optimize out the entire date check before it even begins to do the actual query.  In the case that one is NULL, but the other is not, then the query will use any index on StartDate and/or EndDate optimally by doing an index range scan, and the same is true for UserName.  `@UserName` if it is NULL will get optimized out before the query even begins, and if it is not NULL, then it can make optimal use of any index on the UserName column.

Comment: this show result incorrect, when start date and end date both entered by user